# Variables assigned in chromedp.ActionFunc cannot be inputted by SendKeys

Tags: go, google-chrome-headless, chromedp

I want to assign strings to a variables, after some processes, in `chromedp.ActionFunc`.
Refer to below example.
However, `chromedp.SendKeys` after `chromedp.ActionFunc` couldn't input the variable to a form.
I confirmed the above with `chromedp.CaptureScreenshot`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
        context.Background(),
        chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
    )
    defer cancel()

    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    var value string
    var buf0 []byte
    var buf1 []byte
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(`https://stackoverflow.com/users/login`),
        chromedp.WaitVisible(`//*[@id="submit-button"]`),
        chromedp.CaptureScreenshot(&buf0),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(c context.Context) error {
            value = "apple"
            return nil
        }),
        chromedp.SendKeys(`//*[@id="email"]`, value),
        chromedp.CaptureScreenshot(&buf1),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(value)
    ioutil.WriteFile("./capture0.png", buf0, 0644)
    ioutil.WriteFile("./capture1.png", buf1, 0644)
}
```

It succeeds if `chromedp.SendKeys` be included in `chromedp.ActionFunc` as below.
There is no problem with this method.
But I was wondering why the above approach didn't work.
If you have some knowledge of `chromedp`, please let me know.

```golang
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(c context.Context) error {
            value = "apple"
            chromedp.SendKeys(`//*[@id="email"]`, value).Do(c)
            return nil
        }),
```

Comment: Such an important thing to point out...! The doc did not mention this, pretty confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach doesn't work cause at the moment

```
chromedp.SendKeys(`//*[@id="email"]`, value)
```

is called, the value of variable `value` is empty, so effectively it creates `SendKeys` action with the empty string. If the variable is initialized before calling `chromedp.SendKeys` the behavior would be as it was intended, see the fixed code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
        context.Background(),
        chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
    )
    defer cancel()

    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    var value string = "apple"
    var buf0 []byte
    var buf1 []byte
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(`https://stackoverflow.com/users/login`),
        chromedp.WaitVisible(`//*[@id="submit-button"]`),
        chromedp.CaptureScreenshot(&buf0),
        chromedp.SendKeys(`//*[@id="email"]`, value),
        chromedp.CaptureScreenshot(&buf1),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(value)
    ioutil.WriteFile("./capture0.png", buf0, 0644)
    ioutil.WriteFile("./capture1.png", buf1, 0644)
}
```

EDIT:
This will also work as you expected.

```
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(`https://stackoverflow.com/users/login`),
        chromedp.WaitVisible(`//*[@id="submit-button"]`),
        chromedp.CaptureScreenshot(&buf0),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(c context.Context) error {
            value = "apple"
            return nil
        }),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.SendKeys(`//*[@id="email"]`, value),
        chromedp.CaptureScreenshot(&buf1),
    })
```

Comment: Umm... Can I assign a value to a variable before `SendKeys`?
I want to process the data obtained from the browser with `ActionFunc`, and fill it in the form with `SendKey`.

Comment: The way you did it in the question is fine, i.e. you can assign the value from inside `ActionFunc` and then call `chromedp.SendKeys(`//*[@id="email"]`, value).Do(c)`

Comment: My way of relaying was bad. In this question, I'd like to know WHY variable assigned inside `ActionFunc` cannot be used with `SendKeys` outside `ActionFunc`. Why the value of variable `value` is empty in my first approach?

Comment: The value of variable `value` is empty cause the function which is provided to `chromedp.ActionFunc` (and which assigns "apple" to `value`) is executed after the call to `chromedp.SendKeys`

Comment: I'm wondering why `ActionFunc` is executed after the call to `SendKeys`. My understanding is that `Action`s inside `chromedp.Run` (or `chromedp.Tasks`) are executed in writing order. Is there a way to execute `ActionFunc` before the call to `SendKeys`?

Comment: `chromedp.ActionFunc` is executed before `chromedp.SendKeys`, but the function which you provide as a parameter to `chromedp.ActionFunc` and which assigns "apple" to value is executed after `chromedp.SendKeys`. I'll update the answer to show how to make it work with two calls to `chromedp.Run`

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer! It means that variable assignment in `ActionFunc` works like `defer`. The method of using `Run` twice was a blind spot.